# How to have <div> and <img> in the same cell when using cell.appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this piece of code to create a cell in a table...

```
var cell = row.insertCell(i);
cell.contentEditable = true;
var element = document.createElement("div");
var image= document.createElement("img");
image.src = "pics/grey-button.png";
element.type = "text";
element.className = "boxes";
element.id = tableID+n+""+i;
element.contentEditable = true;
cell.appendChild(element);
cell.appendChild(image);
```

but in each cell I get the image under the `<div>`, how do I get them to be in the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: Add "display: inline;" to css styles?

Comment: @mishik nope, that didn't fix it

Comment: make some jsfiddle with css!

Comment: @SpYk3HH maybe there's a jQuery to do this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5MYZc/
removing "display: inline" will split them in two lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `<div>` is a *block* element, not an *inline* element. If you want it to be rendered inline, you need to tell the browser that the `<div>` is to be displayed as an *inline* element.

```
element.style.display = 'inline'; // or 'inline-block'
```

If it still wrapped to a new line, it is due to size restrictions (e.g. the cell can't grow any more or the `<div>` is growing without leaving space for the `<img>`).
A different way to fix this is by setting `whitespace: nowrap;`, to disable wrapping.

See [**this update**](http://jsfiddle.net/5MYZc/1/) of [**mishik's fiddle**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990991/#comment24547063_16990991), where I limited the size to prevent new line wrapping of the inline element and in [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/5MYZc/2/) I disabled wrapping.

As commented, you can put the `display: inline` as *CSS* to be neater.

Comment: inline isn't necessary. He can just as easily set the margin to `0 auto` and get the same affect of centering without any of the negative side effects you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the divs display to `inline-block` (or use floats if [older](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) browsers is an issue) :

```
var cell = row.insertCell(i);
cell.contentEditable = true;
var element = document.createElement("div");
var image= document.createElement("img");
image.src = "pics/grey-button.png";
element.type = "text";
element.className = "boxes";
element.id = tableID+n+""+i;
element.style.display = 'inline-block';
element.contentEditable = true;
cell.appendChild(element);
cell.appendChild(image);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2QkjV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much easier by just using jQuery, since you marked it.  In jQuery, the exact process of what you have would be something like: (tho there are many ways)

```
var cell = $("<td />").appendTo($("table tr:last")), // this append to statement, you would change the selector to select your row
    div = $("<div />", { id: tableID+n+""+i, class: "boxes", contenteditable: true, type: "text" }).css("margin", "0 auto").appendTo(cell),
    img = $("<img />", { src: "pics/grey-button.png" }).prependTo(div);
```

See a working example with a few more options and another jQuery method 


## here!

---

As for the centering issue. You could do as suggested and use `inline`, however, that could lead to more problems. Just simply set your div to have a margin of `0 auto` and you're good to go. You'll see this done in my CSS in my fiddle example, or in the 2nd line in the code above. The jQuery command is `.css("margin", "0 auto")` or `.css({ margin: "0 auto" })`

Comment: This may be an easier way, but it doesn't answer the actual question.  "how do I get them to be in the same line?"  Your example is just an "easier" way to do exactly what the code already does.

Comment: Not sure what that "neg"ativity comment is about, I didn't downvote you.  If you look at your fiddle, the div and the img are clearly on separate lines.  The text is below the image.

Comment: @randomizertech Np, glad I could help. jQuery really does make javascript a lot easier and shorter. http://api.jquery.com/